# GraphQL mutation implementation in Spring Boot using @GraphQlRepository

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, graphql, spring-data-mongodb, spring-graphql

I have the following Spring Boot reactive "stack" with GraphQL and MongoDB (in Kotlin):

- [spring-boot-starter-webflux](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-webflux)
- [spring-boot-starter-graphql](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-graphql)
- [spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb-reactive](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb-reactive)

A very basic example for a server which exposes a GraphQL API to query customers:

```kotlin
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication
import org.springframework.boot.runApplication
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.ReactiveMongoRepository
import org.springframework.graphql.data.GraphQlRepository

@SpringBootApplication class ServerApplication

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    runApplication<ServerApplication>(*args)
}

@Document
data class Customer(
    @Id val id: String? = null,
    val name: String?,
)

@GraphQlRepository 
interface CustomerRepository : ReactiveMongoRepository<Customer, String>
```

In combination with the following GraphQL schema file

```
type Customer {
    id: ID
    name: String
}

type Query {
    customers: [Customer]
    customerById(id: ID!): Customer
}

type Mutation {
    createCustomer(name: String!): Customer
}
```

It is already possible to query `customers` / `customerById` and retrieve the data accordingly using e.g.:

```
{
  customers { id name }
  customerById(id: "...") { name }
}
```

This is made possible by the `@GraphQlRepository` annotation, which automatically registers a handler for fetching data directly from the database.

However, I can't find anything in the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-graphql/docs/current/reference/html) about **how mutations are implemented** i.e. if there is such a **simple automatic solution** like for the queries or if this has to be implemented **manually by a controller** with `@MutationMapping`.

```kotlin
@Controller
class CustomerController(val customerRepository: CustomerRepository) {
    @MutationMapping
    fun createCustomer(@Argument name: String?): Mono<Customer> {
        return customerRepository.save(Customer(name = name))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, mutations must be implemented through a dedicated, `@MutationMapping` annotated method in the `Controller` like you suggest. I have made a couple of exercises and the only difference from your example is that I have used a special `Input` type -both in the `schema` and in the Java codebase- to define it; in your case, a `String` will do.

The schema:

```
type Query{
    obras: [Obra]
    obrasPorArtista(apellidoArtista:String!): [Obra]
}

type Mutation{
    addObra(nueva: ObraInput): Obra
}

type Obra{
    id: ID
    titulo: String
    precio: Float
}

input ObraInput{
    titulo: String
    artista: String
    precio: Float
}
```

The Controller (the service is injected):

```
@MutationMapping
public Mono<Obra> addObra(@Argument ObraInput nueva){
    return obraService.guardarObra(nueva);
}
```

The ObraInput:

```
public record ObraInput(String titulo, String artista, double precio) {}
```

(The `Obra` is an `Entity` with the JPA annotations, columns, etc)

Hope it helps!

Comment: Yes, I actually use the input types as well, the one from the question was just a simple example to illustrate. Thanks for the answer, but I will not yet accept as a solution, in case someone else has a different idea.